# Chef seeking Windows although not wanted

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning

I'm new to Chef, which I'm using to provision [a Vagrant box](https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty32). I have so far configured for basic recipes like vim and git, but that's spawned a long list of dependency based errors. I have kept obliging, but now it's asking for a Windows cookbook. I would like to keep this lightweight but I'm wondering if I'm taking the wrong approach if it's started asking that (I don't want this box to be Windows-ready!).

What am I doing wrong, if anything?

Error:

```
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:30+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[vim]", "recipe[git]", "recipe[users::ruby_shadow]", "recipe[users::sysadmins]", "recipe[users::sysadmin_sudo]", "recipe[root_ssh_agent::ppid]", "recipe[ssh_known_hosts]", "recipe[homesick_agent::data_bag]"] from JSON
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:30+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[vim], recipe[git], recipe[users::ruby_shadow], recipe[users::sysadmins], recipe[users::sysadmin_sudo], recipe[root_ssh_agent::ppid], recipe[ssh_known_hosts], recipe[homesick_agent::data_bag]]
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:30+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [vim, git, users::ruby_shadow, users::sysadmins, users::sysadmin_sudo, root_ssh_agent::ppid, ssh_known_hosts, homesick_agent::data_bag]
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:30+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:30+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:30+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:31+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:31+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:31+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:31+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook windows not found. If you're loading windows from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:28+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2014-09-17T17:29:31+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Answer (score 2):

You still need the windows cookbook because it is a dependency of something you are using. It won't actually use any recipes from that cookbook, but it does need to be loaded. I recommend using Berkshelf as it takes care of this for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Can't I suppress the dependency manually in order to make it more lightweight? Maybe unnecessary. Btw I think there's a better (more contemporary) solution than Berkshelf: https://sethvargo.com/the-future-of-vagrant-berkshelf/

Comment: No, you cannot. Chef doesn't support any form of optional or conditional dependencies. You would have to fork the upstream cookbooks that depend on it and remove the dependency. That blog post is also out of date, as is made clear at the top of it.

Comment: @KindOfGuy Don't worry about including other platform cookbooks. Ideally chef cookbooks are written to be cross-platform. Just because "windows" is imported doesn't mean it'll be used. Don't forget this is configuration not code. Finally Berkshelf is an essential tool for chef development.